# Android: starting activity landscape wrong orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

I'm facing a strange problem: i have an activity wich launches another activity when orientation changes to landscape. the problem is that the new activity comes in the reverse position when i turn my device clockwise.

Some screenshots to understand...

FirstActivity (runs in portrait mode):
[image]

When i turn the device counterclockwise my second activity is launched and it all works great:
[image]

If i turn my device in portrait orientation the first activity gets called and it's all ok: i can go on turning it again and again and it always works.
The problem is that when i turn my device clockwise i get this:
[image]

Here' the code:

first activity (glanceActivity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_glance_landscape);

    setOrientationChangeListener();
}

private void setOrientationChangeListener() {

    mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){

        long changeStart = 0;

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {

            if (arg0 > 80 && arg0 < 280) {
                if(changeStart == 0) {
                    changeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                else if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - changeStart) > 1500) {
                    launchLandscapeActivity();
                    changeStart = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                changeStart = 0;
            }
        }
    };

    if (mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()){
        mOrientationEventListener.enable();
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}

private void launchLandscapeActivity() {
    mOrientationEventListener.disable();
    Intent intent = new Intent(GlanceActivity.this, GlanceLandscapeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

And here's my second activity (GlanceLandscapeActivity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_glance_landscape);

    setOrientationChangeListener();
}

private void setOrientationChangeListener() {

    mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){

       long changeStart = 0;

       @Override
       public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {

        if ((arg0 <= 360 && arg0 > 280) || (arg0 >= 0 && arg0 < 80)) {
            if(changeStart == 0) {
                changeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            else if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - changeStart) > 1500) {
                launchPortraitActivity();
                changeStart = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            changeStart = 0;
        }
    }
};

if (mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()){
    mOrientationEventListener.enable();
}
else{
    finish();
}
}

private void launchPortraitActivity() {
    mOrientationEventListener.disable();
    Intent intent = new Intent(GlanceLandscapeActivity.this, GlanceActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add the declaration in the manifest.xml :

```
<activity
      android:name=".GlanceActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_glance"
      android:theme="@style/sectionsTheme" >
</activity>
<activity
      android:name=".GlanceLandscapeActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_glance_landscape"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

Comment: why not just use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);` on your landscape activity/

Comment: and the content looks same to me, why are you making two different activities?

Comment: @Chor WaiChun Thank you very much! I didn't think of that... I will try, but I still don't understand why this is happening.

The content is the same because i have only attached the code that manages the orientation and the activity launch. The 2 activities have different layout and different behaviour!

Comment: Well, you're not alone, I can't figure out why too..

Comment: Ok, it worked pretty well!

I've added the orientation as an extra to the intent and done this:

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  int orientation = getIntent().getIntExtra("orientation", 0);
        
  if (orientation < 180) {
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
  }
  else {
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  }


Thank you again!